# How to get field options array from WooCommerce checkout billing country?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, billing

In woocommerce I am using the following code to customize the checkout billing fields using the filter hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` :

[image]

I don't know how to get the array of billing countries key / value pairs for the 'options' key.

How can get in WooCommerce checkout the billing country field options array?

Comment: Same problem here :_(

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of countries:

```
    'AF' => __( 'Afghanistan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AX' => __( 'Åland Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AL' => __( 'Albania', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DZ' => __( 'Algeria', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AS' => __( 'American Samoa', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AD' => __( 'Andorra', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AO' => __( 'Angola', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AI' => __( 'Anguilla', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AQ' => __( 'Antarctica', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AG' => __( 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AR' => __( 'Argentina', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AM' => __( 'Armenia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AW' => __( 'Aruba', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AU' => __( 'Australia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AT' => __( 'Austria', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AZ' => __( 'Azerbaijan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BS' => __( 'Bahamas', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BH' => __( 'Bahrain', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BD' => __( 'Bangladesh', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BB' => __( 'Barbados', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BY' => __( 'Belarus', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BE' => __( 'Belgium', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PW' => __( 'Belau', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BZ' => __( 'Belize', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BJ' => __( 'Benin', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BM' => __( 'Bermuda', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BT' => __( 'Bhutan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BO' => __( 'Bolivia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BQ' => __( 'Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BA' => __( 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BW' => __( 'Botswana', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BV' => __( 'Bouvet Island', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BR' => __( 'Brazil', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IO' => __( 'British Indian Ocean Territory', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BN' => __( 'Brunei', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BG' => __( 'Bulgaria', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BF' => __( 'Burkina Faso', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BI' => __( 'Burundi', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KH' => __( 'Cambodia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CM' => __( 'Cameroon', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CA' => __( 'Canada', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CV' => __( 'Cape Verde', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KY' => __( 'Cayman Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CF' => __( 'Central African Republic', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TD' => __( 'Chad', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CL' => __( 'Chile', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CN' => __( 'China', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CX' => __( 'Christmas Island', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CC' => __( 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CO' => __( 'Colombia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KM' => __( 'Comoros', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CG' => __( 'Congo (Brazzaville)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CD' => __( 'Congo (Kinshasa)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CK' => __( 'Cook Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CR' => __( 'Costa Rica', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HR' => __( 'Croatia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CU' => __( 'Cuba', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CW' => __( 'Cura&ccedil;ao', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CY' => __( 'Cyprus', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CZ' => __( 'Czech Republic', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DK' => __( 'Denmark', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DJ' => __( 'Djibouti', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DM' => __( 'Dominica', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DO' => __( 'Dominican Republic', 'woocommerce' ),
    'EC' => __( 'Ecuador', 'woocommerce' ),
    'EG' => __( 'Egypt', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SV' => __( 'El Salvador', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GQ' => __( 'Equatorial Guinea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ER' => __( 'Eritrea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'EE' => __( 'Estonia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ET' => __( 'Ethiopia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FK' => __( 'Falkland Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FO' => __( 'Faroe Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FJ' => __( 'Fiji', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FI' => __( 'Finland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FR' => __( 'France', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GF' => __( 'French Guiana', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PF' => __( 'French Polynesia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TF' => __( 'French Southern Territories', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GA' => __( 'Gabon', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GM' => __( 'Gambia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GE' => __( 'Georgia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'DE' => __( 'Germany', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GH' => __( 'Ghana', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GI' => __( 'Gibraltar', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GR' => __( 'Greece', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GL' => __( 'Greenland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GD' => __( 'Grenada', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GP' => __( 'Guadeloupe', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GU' => __( 'Guam', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GT' => __( 'Guatemala', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GG' => __( 'Guernsey', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GN' => __( 'Guinea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GW' => __( 'Guinea-Bissau', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GY' => __( 'Guyana', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HT' => __( 'Haiti', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HM' => __( 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HN' => __( 'Honduras', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HK' => __( 'Hong Kong', 'woocommerce' ),
    'HU' => __( 'Hungary', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IS' => __( 'Iceland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IN' => __( 'India', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ID' => __( 'Indonesia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IR' => __( 'Iran', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IQ' => __( 'Iraq', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IE' => __( 'Ireland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IM' => __( 'Isle of Man', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IL' => __( 'Israel', 'woocommerce' ),
    'IT' => __( 'Italy', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CI' => __( 'Ivory Coast', 'woocommerce' ),
    'JM' => __( 'Jamaica', 'woocommerce' ),
    'JP' => __( 'Japan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'JE' => __( 'Jersey', 'woocommerce' ),
    'JO' => __( 'Jordan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KZ' => __( 'Kazakhstan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KE' => __( 'Kenya', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KI' => __( 'Kiribati', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KW' => __( 'Kuwait', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KG' => __( 'Kyrgyzstan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LA' => __( 'Laos', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LV' => __( 'Latvia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LB' => __( 'Lebanon', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LS' => __( 'Lesotho', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LR' => __( 'Liberia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LY' => __( 'Libya', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LI' => __( 'Liechtenstein', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LT' => __( 'Lithuania', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LU' => __( 'Luxembourg', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MO' => __( 'Macao', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MK' => __( 'North Macedonia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MG' => __( 'Madagascar', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MW' => __( 'Malawi', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MY' => __( 'Malaysia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MV' => __( 'Maldives', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ML' => __( 'Mali', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MT' => __( 'Malta', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MH' => __( 'Marshall Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MQ' => __( 'Martinique', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MR' => __( 'Mauritania', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MU' => __( 'Mauritius', 'woocommerce' ),
    'YT' => __( 'Mayotte', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MX' => __( 'Mexico', 'woocommerce' ),
    'FM' => __( 'Micronesia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MD' => __( 'Moldova', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MC' => __( 'Monaco', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MN' => __( 'Mongolia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ME' => __( 'Montenegro', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MS' => __( 'Montserrat', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MA' => __( 'Morocco', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MZ' => __( 'Mozambique', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MM' => __( 'Myanmar', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NA' => __( 'Namibia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NR' => __( 'Nauru', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NP' => __( 'Nepal', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NL' => __( 'Netherlands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NC' => __( 'New Caledonia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NZ' => __( 'New Zealand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NI' => __( 'Nicaragua', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NE' => __( 'Niger', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NG' => __( 'Nigeria', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NU' => __( 'Niue', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NF' => __( 'Norfolk Island', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MP' => __( 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KP' => __( 'North Korea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'NO' => __( 'Norway', 'woocommerce' ),
    'OM' => __( 'Oman', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PK' => __( 'Pakistan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PS' => __( 'Palestinian Territory', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PA' => __( 'Panama', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PG' => __( 'Papua New Guinea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PY' => __( 'Paraguay', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PE' => __( 'Peru', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PH' => __( 'Philippines', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PN' => __( 'Pitcairn', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PL' => __( 'Poland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PT' => __( 'Portugal', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PR' => __( 'Puerto Rico', 'woocommerce' ),
    'QA' => __( 'Qatar', 'woocommerce' ),
    'RE' => __( 'Reunion', 'woocommerce' ),
    'RO' => __( 'Romania', 'woocommerce' ),
    'RU' => __( 'Russia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'RW' => __( 'Rwanda', 'woocommerce' ),
    'BL' => __( 'Saint Barth&eacute;lemy', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SH' => __( 'Saint Helena', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KN' => __( 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LC' => __( 'Saint Lucia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'MF' => __( 'Saint Martin (French part)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SX' => __( 'Saint Martin (Dutch part)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'PM' => __( 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VC' => __( 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SM' => __( 'San Marino', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ST' => __( 'S&atilde;o Tom&eacute; and Pr&iacute;ncipe', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SA' => __( 'Saudi Arabia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SN' => __( 'Senegal', 'woocommerce' ),
    'RS' => __( 'Serbia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SC' => __( 'Seychelles', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SL' => __( 'Sierra Leone', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SG' => __( 'Singapore', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SK' => __( 'Slovakia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SI' => __( 'Slovenia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SB' => __( 'Solomon Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SO' => __( 'Somalia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ZA' => __( 'South Africa', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GS' => __( 'South Georgia/Sandwich Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'KR' => __( 'South Korea', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SS' => __( 'South Sudan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ES' => __( 'Spain', 'woocommerce' ),
    'LK' => __( 'Sri Lanka', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SD' => __( 'Sudan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SR' => __( 'Suriname', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SJ' => __( 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SZ' => __( 'Swaziland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SE' => __( 'Sweden', 'woocommerce' ),
    'CH' => __( 'Switzerland', 'woocommerce' ),
    'SY' => __( 'Syria', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TW' => __( 'Taiwan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TJ' => __( 'Tajikistan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TZ' => __( 'Tanzania', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TH' => __( 'Thailand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TL' => __( 'Timor-Leste', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TG' => __( 'Togo', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TK' => __( 'Tokelau', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TO' => __( 'Tonga', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TT' => __( 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TN' => __( 'Tunisia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TR' => __( 'Turkey', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TM' => __( 'Turkmenistan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TC' => __( 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'TV' => __( 'Tuvalu', 'woocommerce' ),
    'UG' => __( 'Uganda', 'woocommerce' ),
    'UA' => __( 'Ukraine', 'woocommerce' ),
    'AE' => __( 'United Arab Emirates', 'woocommerce' ),
    'GB' => __( 'United Kingdom (UK)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'US' => __( 'United States (US)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'UM' => __( 'United States (US) Minor Outlying Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'UY' => __( 'Uruguay', 'woocommerce' ),
    'UZ' => __( 'Uzbekistan', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VU' => __( 'Vanuatu', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VA' => __( 'Vatican', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VE' => __( 'Venezuela', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VN' => __( 'Vietnam', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VG' => __( 'Virgin Islands (British)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'VI' => __( 'Virgin Islands (US)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'WF' => __( 'Wallis and Futuna', 'woocommerce' ),
    'EH' => __( 'Western Sahara', 'woocommerce' ),
    'WS' => __( 'Samoa', 'woocommerce' ),
    'YE' => __( 'Yemen', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ZM' => __( 'Zambia', 'woocommerce' ),
    'ZW' => __( 'Zimbabwe', 'woocommerce' )
```

To modify the list of countries you can do:

```
function update_woo_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Only allow "Jamaica" as the option
    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = [
        'type' => 'select',
        'required' => 'true',
        'class' => [ 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ],
        'label' => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => [
            'JM' => __( 'Jamaica', 'woocommerce' ),
        ],
    ];

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'update_woo_checkout_fields' );
```